# How do you remove a hard drive password on a Lenovo Y580?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, bios, passwords, lenovo-laptop

I've got a Lenovo IdeaPad Y580 with hard drive passwords enabled for both drives.

The circumstances (frequent travel) that prompted me to install hard drive passwords are no longer in my life, so I'd like to remove these passwords.

I have reset the BIOS using options in the BIOS. This did not remove the passwords I have to type in BIOS before I can boot the system with the drives install.

I have all applicable BIOS passwords for this system. It is my personal property, so there's no special corporate or company software in play that would prohibit this.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to find information about the BIOS passwords for this model. The user manuals refer to the on screen instructions.

According to this https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/W-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/Can-t-remove-HDD-password/td-p/241538 entering the the supervisor password is necessary.

> did you by any chance also set a supervisor password?  If you did,
>   press F1 immediately you see the message "to interrupt ....." and
>   enter the supervisor password at the prompt. If the HD password is
>   different to the supervisor password you will then be required to
>   enter it.
>
> You should then have the ability to disable the HD password.

According to this [forum post](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-Y-U-V-Z-and-P-series/hard-disk-password-ideapad-y580/td-p/891573) about the Y580:

> You need to put on master password same password as system password
>   than reset them bouth by adding no password (pressing enter)
>
> Than the hdd password will be removed
>
> Had same problem this is how i fixed and yes i own an y580

[Instructions for older Thinkpad models](http://support.lenovo.com/en_LK/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?&LegacyDocID=YAST-3JXNTY) indicate that entering the password followed by a space then pressing Enter will disable the password.

Comment: This element of your post fixed the problem:

"You need to put on master password same password as system password than reset them bouth by adding no password (pressing enter)"

Answer (score 0):

The following procedure used to remove known HDD passwords in some older ThinkPads. Maybe Lenovo is still using it

> You must remove your password at the password prompt that appears when
>   you turn on the computer. To remove the password, at the prompt: Enter
>   your current password, press the Spacebar and then press Enter.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. Any attempts to enter a space into the hard disk password fields are met with an error beep.

Answer (score 0):

Only the surpervisor password can disable both if this is set. If you forget it, the user might have a problem there.

To disable use of HD password, enter the current password in the change password screen and nothing in the new password field. This should disable it.

Answer (score -1):

had similar issue, see solution here http://www.mbg-tech.com/can-remove-lenovo-laptop-hardrive-password-t60t61/

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.